# Create a column that is the average of three other columns in a table -SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My database contains a table that contains 3 grades, say:

```
grade_1, grade_2 and grade_3
```

I want to add another row in my table which contains the average of this three grades:

```
ALTER TABLE grades
ADD COLUMN ... ???
```

Thank you.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Consider revising your schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```
alter table grades
add column average int as ((grade_1 + grade_2 + grade_3) / 3);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rsan47QAiiDWcAJYrYaD9n/0).

Comment: using computed column is better than creating triggers +1

Answer (score 0):

a nice solution would be using trigger for fill the column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `default_average_value` 
AFTER INSERT ON `grades` 
FOR EACH ROW  
    UPDATE `grades` SET `grade_average` = SUM(grade_1+grade_2+grade_3)/3;
```

Comment: @forpas yes it does, and because of that, I think above solution is better. whoever above solution also need an action after updating a row